# How to work with output from ldapsearch in bash

Tags: bash, ldap, openldap

lets say I have output from ldapsearch in this format:

```
dn: user1...
dateOfExpire: someDate
dn: user2
dateOfExpire: someDate
....
```

How can I do something like this:

```
if [ "$someDate" = "$now" ]; then
    echo "same day"
elif expr "$someDate" "<" "$now" >/dev/null; then
    do some action with user account which date is expired
fi
```

This succesfully compare two dates, but I don't know how to work with related account.

Thanks all

Comment: What is the format of date in `dateOfExpire: someDate` ?

Comment: It is in this fomat: `20170406000000.202Z` This is required by my LDAP settings. But I suppose there is no problem get this by cut or something to only 20170406 - I this case I don't care about hours, minutes etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

ldapDate='20170406000000'
today=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d 00:00:00')
someDate=$(sed -E 's|^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*$|\1/\2/\3 00:00:00|g' <<< $ldapDate)
today_t=$(date -d "$today" '+%s')
somedate_t=$(date -d "$someDate" '+%s')

if [[ "$somedate_t" -eq "$today_t" ]]; then
    echo "Same Day"
elif [[ "$somedate_t" -le "$today_t" ]]; then
    echo "Expired"
elif [[ "$somedate_t" -ge "$today_t" ]]; then
    echo "Not Expired"
else
    echo "Unknown"
fi
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but I guess this doen't solve my problem - how to eg. remove from LDAP DN which is expired, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU `date`, you can convert the dates to Epoch, do simple integer comparison, and get the exit status to do further operation. For example:

```
% date -d 'yesterday' '+%s'
1494314230
% date '+%s'               
1494400638

% (( $(date '+%s') > $(date -d 'yesterday' '+%s') ))
% echo $?
0

% (( $(date '+%s') < $(date -d 'yesterday' '+%s') ))
% echo $?                                           
1
```